# Java Application + Logging

Tags: java, logging

I am bit confused so, thought to ask experts.

I have written small java application. I have function which reads properties files which contains the path of the directory where to write the log and exceptions. Lets say I get exception while reading the properties file since logger wouldn't have been initialized by that time, how can I know that there was an error or exception? If I have written e.printStackTrace() in catch block where it will be printed? I am running this application through windows scheduler.

Thanks for advice.

BR
SC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about Log4j. That was useful when logging capabilites were not embbeded inside JRE itself. You can configure the logging properties by a means of a logging.properties file (which is provided at JVM start point). Inside the application you can log messages with different levels of severity with or without nested exceptions.

[Here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=143) is a useful page with example of basic configuration and logging capabilites use.

Comment: Thanks. I am already using java.util.logging. Will follow the link to implement at global level. So, there can be only ONE global log for all applications? Can I create separate log in particular for each different application. BR. SC

Comment: I got it... I can use java.util.logging.config.file=myLoggingConfigFilePath... it should contain the log file name as well? e.g. "d:\test\logging.properties". Thanks. SC.

Comment: # (The output file is placed in the directory
# defined by the "user.home" System property.)
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=%h/java%u.log. Is it necessary to define the "user.home" system property? I want o have separate file in separate folder for different application. BR. SC.

Comment: No, you do not need to define a "user.home". By default is current directory of running JVM. If you run different applications I assume you run different JVMs, so there is no problem at all (you use different configuration files each time).

Answer (score 1):

Use [**log4j**](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) configure it [here it will configure it self by using log4j.properties or .xml from the classpath ] , initialize it in app startup and use it app wide.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know for sure that the exception was thrown, don't catch it :) 
The `printStackTrace()` writes to stderr. You could run your app though console to read it. 
If you want to log no matter what without any config or extra libs, you can use [java-util.logging](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) which is bundled with the jdk and writes to stdout by default